# Roughly how many US White House political vs non-political staff have a "radio which announces the President’s logistical movements"?

Tags: united-states, president

From Politico's May 9, 2022 [How the Jan. 6 panel broke through Trump allies’ stonewalling](https://www.politico.com/news/2022/05/09/jan-6-panel-donald-trump-allies-00030781):

> Aides like Cassidy Hutchinson, a close adviser to former Trump chief of staff Mark Meadows, and Ken Klukowski, who advised former Justice Department official Jeffrey Clark, have helped the select committee fill in gaps about Trump’s private meetings, calls and efforts to overturn the 2020 election that investigators could otherwise only obtain from the principal players themselves.

> [Hutchinson’s testimony](https://www.washingtonpost.com/politics/2022/04/25/cassidy-hutchinson-mark-meadows/) offered granular details about numerous meetings and phone calls that Meadows convened to discuss options for preventing Joe Biden from taking office. She identified a long list of Republican members of Congress who participated in those meetings — several of whom have themselves refused to cooperate with the investigation.
>
> In addition, Hutchinson described pushback from the White House Counsel’s office to legal theories pushed by lawmakers and Trump allies on how to thwart election results, and she was able to identify when many key figures met with Trump himself.
>
> “Almost all, if not all, meetings Mr. Trump had, I had insight on,” Hutchinson told the committee.
>
> In excerpts of her testimony released by the committee, Hutchinson also described Meadows’ post-election trip to Georgia, where he met with aides to Secretary of State Brad Raffensperger amid Trump’s effort to pressure the state to reverse his defeat. Plus, she described Meadows’ movements on Jan. 6 — from his early efforts to contact Rep. Jim Jordan (R-Ohio) and Rudy Giuliani to his time with Trump.
>
> **“When I had gotten to the West Wing, he was in the Oval dining room,” Hutchinson said of Trump.**
>
> **“How do you know that?” committee investigator Dan George asked in her February interview.**
>
> **“Because I heard it announced on my radio which announces the president’s logistical movements,” Hutchinson replied.**

The article also links to a previous WaPo article discussing Hutchinson's testimony: [Meadows was warned of violence before Jan. 6, new court filings show](https://www.washingtonpost.com/politics/2022/04/23/meadows-jan6-secret-service-committee-testimony/)

The political aspect of this question are at least two fold:

1. The radio and contemporaneous notes and recollection of what is announced makes getting a record of presidential movement and behavior at key moments of great political consequence easier.
2. Those can also reveal the existence of conflicting and/or misleading statements about the same presidential movement and behavior at key moments.

But neither WaPo article mentions a "radio which announces the President’s logistical movements" referenced by Politico.

Politico describes Cassidy Hutchinson as "a close adviser to former Trump Chief of Staff Mark Meadows" and not secret service, so I am not asking about presidential protection. But I would like to know:

**Question:** Roughly how many US White House political vs non-political staff<sup>1</sup> have a "radio which announces the President’s logistical movements"?

Is this common and widespread? Are there dozens of people with these radios? Did/does it happen in presidential administrations before and after this one as well?

---

<sup>1</sup>"political vs non-political staff" derived from a discussion in comments.

Comment: I don't see how the number of radios or who has them in an given administration is a good fit for this site especially when you are asking for it in general but it can change from administration to administration depending on how they feel about it.

Comment: @JoeW I understand that you don't at the moment, but let's wait and see how answers by others develop (it may become clearer once further information emerges) rather than reiterating variations of "nobody knows the answer to this because I don't".

Comment: This is most likely an extreme nit-pick, but I'm curious why you insist on using the phrase "political staff" vs just "staff" - Not all WH staff are what I would term 'political', as in brought in for and by the current administration. There are plenty of WH staff which are (supposed to be) non-political and/or non-partisan. Yes, even in today's very partisan climate. (i.e. the office of the Usher and other staff who remain not only during an administration but between them as well.

Comment: @CGCampbell and I'm *particularly curious* why you chose the loaded word "insist" instead of simply "chose" or "used". **Check the edit history** to see what I wrote originally. Fizz's comment is no longer here; if it were you'd see that changing to "political" was in response to that comment. Folks that don't ask many question don't understand how challenging it can be to try to make everybody sufficiently happy that the question stays open so that it can be answered. In this case the change was made in response to one user's comment, so of course now another user is complaining about it.

Comment: Yep, I missed that change, sure enough. And sorry. Actually, I'd have had the same nitpick with the word 'regular' there. There are two 'sets' of WH employees for any given administration. There are the political ones, brought in by the administration, and what I would call the regular ones, who are there both during an administration and between them, regardless of the politics of any given current POTUS. I would be curious who on both sets has knowledge of the President's exact and current location within the WH. What we never heard on West Wing: "the POTUS is in the can, I repeat..."

Comment: @CGCampbell there's no "between" administrations.  Some offices may be vacant for a short time, but the new president's term begins at noon, the same moment when the previous president's ends.  Any cabinet posts vacated by a secretary who resigns before a successor can be appointed will be filled by a subordinate in an acting capacity.

Comment: @phoog Yes, I am quite aware. I did not mean between as in a period of time after one administration and before the next one takes over. I meant it that the same staff are there during one administration then the next. The examples I gave were the office of the usher and perhaps the cooks, etc. i.e. those that take care of the actual house, and not necessarily the current "occupant." They might still have need to be in the know about where the POTUS and family are at all times.